# Which are the best way to go through a series of elements with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of elements

```
<div id="lista">
    <ul>
      <li class="seto">Element 1</li>
      <li class="seto">Element 1</li>
      <li class="seto">Element 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then i'm using jquery, it's better do this?:

```
$("#lista li").each(function(){ //something };
```

or this?:

```
$(".seto").each(function(){ //something });
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is a matter of opinion and depends, but I would say the first one is better as it is more specific, but it is much of a much. If you had items with the class ```seto``` elsewhere in the doc perhaps you wouldnt want to affect these

Comment: Or of course: `$("#lista .seto").each(...)`, which is what I'd do **if** I wanted to only process the `.seto` elements inside that particular list.

Comment: FYI, this isn't valid HTML markup. Now maybe you don't even need an each loop, depending what you are trying to do/ method to use

Comment: Re @A.Wolff's point: You can't have `li` as the direct child of `div`. It has to be a direct child of `ol` or `ul`.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry i fix it, this is inside of a ul

Answer (score 2):

You can read about selector optimizatoin here:
https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/.

The $("#lista").children('li') will be the fastes.
But in your case performance is not so important, so you can use whatever you prefer.

Comment: I see last update regarding this article is `March 11, 2015` but as now for all modern browsers jQuery uses internally `document.querySelectorAll()` for CSS selector, this statement e.g seems no more relevant: `The .find() approach is faster because the first selection is handled without going through the Sizzle selector engine – ID-only selections are handled using document.getElementById(), which is extremely fast because it is native to the browser.`  But anyway, good reading for sure. EDIT: `$("#lista > li")` should be slightly faster than `$("#lista").children('li')` i guess

Comment: ↑↑↑ But this is battling for nano seconds optimization so doesn't really matter

Comment: Yes, apparently all optimization has no sense with modern browsers, but we always have an old IE :). However I think in OP's case performance is not an issue at all. About $("#lista > li") vs $("#lista").children('li') - i believe they'll do the same work inside Sizzle engine, but don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Performance will not be an issue I think.

Your jquery should reflect your intent of the code.

Depending of your want to apply styling, I would choose the class version.

If you want to do some post-processing on specific business objects, I would use the ID version.

Having said that, I think you should use the class version, and make sure that the business objects have the correct classes to attach the styling to. Including jQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your case

**Case 1:**
For exxample ur case is like this means

```
<div id="lista">
        <li class="seto">Element 1</li>
        <li class="seto">Element 1</li>
        <li class="seto">Element 1</li>
        <ol class="seto">diff Element 1<ol>
 </div>
```

If you want to go through list of all "*seto*" contain class elements

Then u go for second method. Or else you can use first method